# MySQL query correct syntax is not working in JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-jdbc

I'm using `LIKE` keyword to query form a table with single search parameter. When I run the following sql statement in MySQL Workbench, it's working properly as expected.

```
SET @search = 'B'; 
SELECT T.*,D.divisionname 
FROM Township AS T INNER JOIN Division AS D ON T.divisionid=D.divisionid 
WHERE T.townshipcode LIKE CONCAT('%', @search, '%') OR 
T.townshipname LIKE CONCAT('%', @search, '%') OR 
D.divisionname LIKE CONCAT('%', @search, '%') 
ORDER BY T.townshipcode LIMIT 0,10
```

But, when I execute form my java code with `JdbcTemplate`, I got `BadSqlGrammarException`. The following is my java code :

```
public List<Township> getList(Integer pageNumber, Integer pageDisplayLength, String searchParameter) {
    int start = ((pageNumber - 1) * pageDisplayLength);
    String query = "";
    if (null != searchParameter && !searchParameter.equals("")){

        query = "SET @search = '" + searchParameter + "'; " +
                "SELECT T.*,D.divisionname FROM Township AS T " +
                "INNER JOIN Division AS D ON T.divisionid=D.divisionid " +
                "WHERE T.townshipcode LIKE CONCAT('%', @search, '%') OR " +
                "T.townshipname LIKE CONCAT('%', @search, '%') OR " +
                "D.divisionname LIKE CONCAT('%', @search, '%') " +
                "ORDER BY T.townshipcode LIMIT " + start + "," + pageDisplayLength;                     
    }
    else{
        query = "SELECT T.*,D.divisionname FROM Township AS T " +
               "INNER JOIN Division AS D ON T.divisionid=D.divisionid ORDER BY T.townshipcode LIMIT " + start + "," + pageDisplayLength;
    }
    List<Township> townshipList = getMultiRecords(query);
    return townshipList;
}
```

And the following is `getMultiRecords` method for it's base class :

```
protected List<T> getMultiRecords(String query){
    List<T> listResult = jdbcTemplate.query(query, new RowMapper<T>(){
        @Override 
        public T mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            T entity = readRecord(rs);
            return entity;
        }
    });
    return listResult;
}
```

Here is my `BadSqlGrammarException` details.

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SET @search = 'B'; SELECT T.*,D.divisionname FROM Township AS T INNER JOIN Division AS D ON T.divisionid=D.divisionid WHERE T.townshipcode LIKE CONCAT('%', @search, '%') OR T.townshipname LIKE CONCAT('%', @search, '%') OR D.divisionname LIKE CONCAT('%', @search, '%') ORDER BY T.townshipcode LIMIT 0,10]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT T.*,D.divisionname FROM Township AS T INNER JOIN Division AS D ON T.divis' at line 1
```

Please help me to find out what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that the parser is unhappy about the two statements you are using in one statement. Instead of doing a `SET` and adding all parameters to a `String` you should generally use                                                                           [parameter binding](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html). I wouldn't be surprised if the set statement is unsupported.

You statement misses the closing semicolon as well. As you are missing the exact/full error message it's only guesswork.

Comment: I already tried with parameter binding. But, it's not working too.

Comment: You should post the errortext of the "BadGrammarException" and let us know where exactly the error happens. Did you try leaving out the "T.*" wildcard?

Comment: For testing remove the set and remove all occurrences of "@search" with 'B' afterwards, when it is working change it to parameter binding. I added the Spring documentation link above.

Comment: Parameter binding is work for normal characters. But, when I try to search with unicode character, I got uncategorized SQLException.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the search specific query to named parameter. And call the method appropriate parameters.

```
query =   "SELECT T.*,D.divisionname FROM Township AS T " +
                "INNER JOIN Division AS D ON T.divisionid=D.divisionid " +
                "WHERE T.townshipcode LIKE CONCAT('%', :search, '%') OR " +
                "T.townshipname LIKE CONCAT('%', :search, '%') OR " +
                "D.divisionname LIKE CONCAT('%', :search, '%') " +
                "ORDER BY T.townshipcode LIMIT " + start + "," + pageDisplayLength;  

Map<String, Object> queryParams = new HashMap<>();
queryParams.put("search", searchParameter);
```

Update the method code to accept named params.

```
protected List<T> getMultiRecords(String query, Map<String,Object> namedParams){ 
    List<T> listResult = new ArrayList();
    if (namedParams != null && namedParams.size() > 0) {
        listResult = jdbcTemplate.query(query, namedParams ,new RowMapper<T>(){
            @Override 
            public T mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                T entity = readRecord(rs);
                return entity;
            }
        });
    } else {
        listResult = jdbcTemplate.query(query ,new RowMapper<T>(){
            @Override 
            public T mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                T entity = readRecord(rs);
                return entity;
            }
        });
    }
    return listResult;
}
```